# Is it possible to disable SSLv3 for all Java applications?

Tags: java, poodle-attack

Because of the Poodle attack it is now recommended to disable SSLv3 for client and server applications and only allow TLS 1.0 -TLS 1.2 connections.

Is there a way to disable SSLv3 for all Java based applications (server and client) on a computer without having to modify every Java program?

May be there is a possibility to change the configuration of the JRE or using a special environment variable.

Does anybody know such a way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java http clients and POODLE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26429751/java-http-clients-and-poodle)

Answer (score 4):

You have not specified the version of Java because below Java 8 there is no way to disallow or disable specific SSL protocol but in Java 8 you can set the enabled protocols like following

Statically:

```
% java -Djdk.tls.client.protocols="TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2" MyApp
```

Dynamically:

```
java.lang.System.setProperty("jdk.tls.client.protocols", "TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2");
```

If you are still using java 7 or below try to use work around explained [Instructions to disable SSL v3.0 in Oracle JDK and JRE](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/cve-2014-3566-2342133.html)

I just implemented following piece of code to disallow SSLv3 and SSLv2Hello on one of our Java6 application.

```
if(disabledSSLProtocols != null) {

    String[] protocols = sslEngine.getEnabledProtocols();
    List<String> protocolList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String s : protocols) {

        if (disabledSSLProtocols.contains(s)) {

            log4j.info("{} protocol is disabled", s);
            continue;
        }

        log4j.info("{} protocol is enabled", s);
        protocolList.add(s);
    }

    sslEngine.setEnabledProtocols(protocolList.toArray(new String[0]));
}
```

Where `disabledSSLProtocols` initialized with  `SSLv3,SSLv2Hello`

Comment: This will only affect Java **clients**. Check [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https)

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/tlsreadme-141115.html

Relevant part:

> Renegotiations can be re-enabled for those applications that need it by setting the new system property sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation to true before the JSSE library is initialized. There are several ways to set this property:
>   Command Line:
>   % java -Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true Main
>   Java Control Panel (Java Plug-in / Java Web Start) - Runtime Environment.
>   Within the application:
>   java.lang.System.setProperty("sun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation", true);
>   Note that TLS/SSL renegotiation will not occur unless both client and server have enabled renegotiations.

It explains the issue and the fix.

Comment: Are you sure that the unsafe-renegotiation is relevant for the poodle-attck?

Comment: Yes, very much so. The attack works because it can force a lower protocol (SSL3 instead of TLS). By disabling renegotiation, you disable the attack,

Comment: Fall back mechanism and renegotiation are different.  Fall back will try to create a connection using the most recent protocol and try a less recent if it fails.  Renegotiation is changing the ssl connection after the connection is successfully established.

Answer (score 1):

For https-connections using the java.net-package you could try using the environment-variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS` to set the system-property `https.protocols`:

```
_JAVA_OPTIONS=-Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1,TLSv1.1,TLSv1.2
```

should enable only the mentioned protocols. Note that before Java 7 the maximum supported version was TLSv1.

This solution will not affect any other SSL-connections or http-connections using e.g. the apache-http-connector.

Comment: This will only affect Java **clients**. Check [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/diagnosing-tls,-ssl,-and-https)

Answer (score 0):

You can patch Oracle Java now. 
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/cve-2014-3566-2342133.html