# server certificate change is restricted during renegotiation

Tags: java, ssl, weblogic, java-6

I am using java 1.6 in my machine and currently I am facing the below exception.

```
JSSESocketFactory.makeSocket ldap. ... :636, server certificate change is restricted during renegotiation
```

for an work around I have updated below properties into my weblogic configuration setup

```
-Dsun.security.ssl.allowUnsafeRenegotiation=true 
-Djdk.tls.allowUnsafeServerCertChange=true
```

But Still I am getting server certificate change is restricted during negotiation.

Please let me know if there is anything else I can update in the configuration.

Thanks for your help guys.

Comment: Disable SSLv2 and SSLv3 and only enable TLS protocols.

Comment: @Rahul do you know any specific location where we can update in weblogic.

Comment: Check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27105004/what-means-javax-net-ssl-sslhandshakeexception-server-certificate-change-is-re

Comment: @Rahul, still the issue has not solved. I tried in the production but still I am facing the same issue.