# server certificate change is restricted during renegotiation for TLS_1.2 with Java 8

Tags: java, spring, apache, tomcat, ssl

I am pretty new to SSL and have been hit by what seems like known issue. My application is the SSL client and invokes another component which is enabled for two way SSL. The certificates in both the components are proper and connection works fine sometimes. Each server has its own server certificate and private key , but same root and intermediate certificate.

The SSL check in Server is done in Apache SW LB.

```
                                                                            |-------------|
                                                                          / |   Tomcat1   |
                                                         |-------------| /  |-------------| 
                                             |---------->|Apache SW LB |/ 
                                             |           |-------------|\       
                                             |                           \
                                             |                            \  |-------------|
|-----------|            |------------|      |                               |  Tomcat 2   |
|SSL Client |---HTTPS--->|Hardware LB |------|                               |-------------|    
|-----------|            |------------|      |                              |-------------| 
                                             |                            / |   Tomcat3   |
                                             |           |-------------| /  |-------------|
                                             |---------->|Apache SW LB |/   
                                                         |-------------|\
                                                                         \
                                                                          \|-------------|  
                                                                           |    Tomcat4  |
                                                                           |-------------|
```

Sometimes I am getting an error as below:-

```
***
%% Invalidated:  [Session-10, TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256]
http-nio-8443-exec-10, SEND TLSv1.2 ALERT:  fatal, description = bad_certificate
http-nio-8443-exec-10, WRITE: TLSv1.2 Alert, length = 2
[Raw write]: length = 7
0000: 15 03 03 00 02 02 2A                               ......*
http-nio-8443-exec-10, called closeSocket()
http-nio-8443-exec-10, handling exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: server certificate change is restricted during renegotiation
```

I am using Spring REST template to invoke the REST call and using only TLS_V1.2, but still getting the above error.

```
TrustStrategy ts = new TrustStrategy() {
      @Override
      public boolean isTrusted(
          X509Certificate[] x509Certificates, String s)
          throws CertificateException {
        return true; // TODO : revisit
      }
    };
    SSLContext sslcontext = org.apache.http.ssl.SSLContexts.custom()
        .loadKeyMaterial(keyStore, keypass.toCharArray())
        .loadTrustMaterial(trustStore, ts) 
        .build();

 SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(

            sslcontext, new String[] {
                "TLSv1.2" }, null,
            SSLSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);   
        return HttpClients.custom().setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

      }
```

ON googling i find like that this issue will not be happeneing for TLSv1.2 and Java 8(java version "1.8.0_60"). I am using Spring 4 RestTemplete for invoking rest calls.

And I am using the below version of httpclinet :-

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
        <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Since I am new to SSL , i have few questions to start with:-

1). Is this a SSL clinet or SSL server issue?

2). Any real reason why the connection is working sometimes and breaking sometime?The technical reason for the failure.

3). Is this to do with any caching at client side

Also it be great if someone can point to the real slotion for this issue.

Comment: On goolging what i can find is that with java verison Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_60-b27) and httpClient 4.4.1 we should not be getting this error.But I am still getting this...

Comment: How do you initialize your `sslContext` variable?

Comment: I have added the details you have requested into the question

Comment: Have you tried to set up a protocol on the `sslContext` object? Try to use `SSLContexts.custom().useProtocol("TLSv1.2")`, does it work?

Comment: I have not tried that.So do you think the error "server-certificate-change-is-restricted-during-renegotiation" can happen even though we mention TLS_1.2 in SSLConnectionSocketFactory  and using Java 8 and its an issue with the SSL client?I was doubting on the issue to be with SSL server, as the java error desctiption on this problem says that the issue will not occur on java 1,8  (Ref:- Full details can be found here: Java http clients and POODLE)

Comment: Just to confirm, I expect your two "Apache SW LB" use same private keys and same certificate, is that correct ?

Comment: No.Both the Apache SW LB are on different servers and have different SSL server certificates. But same root and intermediate certificate.

Answer (score 2):

Java SSL stack rejects re-negotiation probably after hardware loadbalancer has switched your connexion from one node to the other.

For such a deployment to work, both "Apache SW LB" instances have to use the **very same** virtual host URL and SSL configurations. And there is no obvious reason not do to so, as it does not conflict with any system configurations.

So your issue is a mixed between a client behaviour that rejects your cluster deployment for which each node use a different private key / server certificate, even if virtual host URL is the same.

Comment: Yes. You are right that its when the F5 load balancer sents the request to the second node the failure happens.Th URL the client is hitting the Hardware F5 load balancer.I mean the IP specified in the REST url is of the F5 load balancer.Is there anything specific in Apache load balancer that can cause this issue. The logical reason behind this is that the same rest clinet is able to interact with other componets behind the F5 load balancer without issue. The only reason difference is the Apache Load Balancer in between...

Comment: Do you use F5 BigIP ? Why not setting it as SSL termination and directly load-balance with HTTP traffic to Tomcat nodes ? It would be far easier and reliable and even better for performance removing Apache intermediates.

Comment: Probably other components you mention has lower traffic or faster response times, without raising conditions that triggers F5 to switch connexions to other nodes.