# Unix Daemon Process over SSL/TLS

Tags: protocols

How does one verify that the unix daemon process configured on the DB server is running over an `SSL` or `TLS` protocol? My application supports Java and it has the ssl provider:

> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.Provider

I am using Linux Redhat and SQL DB, and Daemonize to run it.

Comment: Could you please give us some information about what flavor of linux and what database server you're running?  Also, is your application set up to run using something like daemonize?  Need more details to answer this one.  Thanks!

Comment: Java versions since POODLE disable SSLv3 by default; if you are running on 7u75 or 8u31 or later and your app doesn't re-enable it, you're fine, see http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/cve-2014-3566-2342133.html . For Apache httpclient (in a daemon?) also see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26429751/java-http-clients-and-poodle .