# Apache HttpClient handshake failure with TLSv1.2

Tags: java, ssl, wso2, wso2-esb

First of all, I'll explain the scenario.

I have a WSO2 ESB-4.6.0 (that uses Apache's HttpClient) running with  `jdk1.7.0_79`, and my goal is to call an external secure service that only accepts `TLSv1.2` protocol, without to update the Java to the version 8.
The external server directives are:

```
Supported versions: TLSv1.2
Deflate compression: no
Supported cipher suites (ORDER IS NOT SIGNIFICANT):
  TLSv1.2
     RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
     RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_128_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256
     RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
     DHE_RSA_WITH_CAMELLIA_256_CBC_SHA
     TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_3DES_EDE_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
     TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
----------------------
Minimal encryption strength:     strong encryption (96-bit or more)
Achievable encryption strength:  strong encryption (96-bit or more)
BEAST status: protected
CRIME status: protected
```

So, building and calling a simple proxy, which have an endpoint poiting to this service, results in:

```
Using SSLEngineImpl.
Allow unsafe renegotiation: false
Allow legacy hello messages: true
Is initial handshake: true
Is secure renegotiation: false
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1, fatal error: 40: Couldn't kickstart handshaking
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1, SEND TLSv1 ALERT:  fatal, description = handshake_failure
HTTPS-Sender I/O dispatcher-1, WRITE: TLSv1 Alert, length = 2
[2016-02-25 22:15:12,689] ERROR - TargetHandler I/O error: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
        at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.activate(Handshaker.java:470)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.kickstartHandshake(SSLEngineImpl.java:714)
        at sun.security.ssl.SSLEngineImpl.beginHandshake(SSLEngineImpl.java:740)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.SSLIOSession.bind(SSLIOSession.java:141)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.ssl.SSLClientIOEventDispatch.connected(SSLClientIOEventDispatch.java:205)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.sessionCreated(BaseIOReactor.java:250)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.processNewChannels(AbstractIOReactor.java:425)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractIOReactor.execute(AbstractIOReactor.java:289)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.BaseIOReactor.execute(BaseIOReactor.java:104)
        at org.apache.http.impl.nio.reactor.AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor$Worker.run(AbstractMultiworkerIOReactor.java:542)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

At this point, my first thought was to find a way to "configure" the Java 7 to work with this. So, I did build a simple webservice client class with Eclipse (using `javax.xml.soap.SOAPConnectionFactory`) and run it with the same JVM that the ESB uses. As expected, same error!
However, I edited the `jre/lib/security/java.security` file and found this parameters that makes the call work:

```
java MyClientClass -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 -Dhttps.cipherSuites=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

After all this, I thought the same parameters applied to the ESB should work. But the two parameters above and the others below, in many different combinations, not make it happen, having the same exception as before.

```
./wso2server.sh -Ddeployment.security.SSLv3=false \
                -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1=false \
                -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.1=false \
                -Ddeployment.security.TLSv1.2=true \
                -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 \
                -Dhttps.cipherSuites=TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256
```

Why the ESB, with the same JVM and the same arguments does not works, and `MyClientClass` do? The problem is in Apache's http-core implementation (as stack trace points)? I made some mistake or this parameters are simply ignored?

The HttpCore version is 4.1.3.

Comment: The `https.protocols` property is used by `HttpsUrlConnection`, but it looks, from the stacktrace, that the ESB code is using Apache's `HttpClient` (which does not honor `https.protocols`); see this post for a related discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26429751/4072843

Comment: I see. So an "alternative" for Apache's client remains unknown.

Comment: Using Java 7, yes.  *If* you _could_ upgrade to Java 8, then you would be able to use the "jdk.tls.client.protocols" system property that was [added as a security enhancement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/security/enhancements-8.html).

Comment: I have tested with java 8 and it works, but it also causes problems with another components of the ESB.

Comment: This has been identified as bug[1] and fixed in ESB 4.9.0.Contact the wso2 support team ,they may have patch for ESB 4.6.0. or try to upgrade to java 8 and set following  jdk.tls.client.protocols=TLSv1.2 in java.security.

[1]https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-3644

Answer (score 0):

This issue is old enough that the best answer now would be to please use the [latest version of API Manager](https://wso2.com/api-manager/) with Micro Integrator to [achieve this goal of using TLS1.2](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/setup/transport_configurations/configuring-transports/#configuring-transport-level-security). You'll also want to [disable weak ciphers](https://ei.docs.wso2.com/en/7.0.0/micro-integrator/setup/transport_configurations/configuring-transports/#disabling-weak-ciphers).

By the way, the suggested update to ESB 4.9.1 is no longer valid since ESB 4.9 was discontinued [Sep 10, 2019](https://wso2.com/products/support-matrix/).