# Connecting TLS from java code

Tags: java, ssl, tomcat7, tls1.2

I have a requirement where is have to implement tls,
I know how to make my server tls enabled using tomcat, but have no idea how to make a tls call from within java code.

I have an application which is running on web server(tomcat) which supports tls1.0, 1.1 and 1.2 and sslv3.
From this application i have to call 2 web service, one is running on TLS1.0 and the other supports only sslv3.

How can my code connect to this 2 web service which runs on 2 different protocol.

Regards,

Comment: How do you make http connections currently? It usually just requires you to change the url from `http://..` to `https://..` since protocol version negotiation is built into the ssl/tls protocol and every https capable library can do that for you, except some will have sslv3 disabled because it's as secure as plain http: http://disablessl3.com/#faq and e.g. apache-http http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26429751/java-http-clients-and-poodle

Comment: i use https protocol to connect to the webservice, my concern was out of 2 web service, i has sslv3 disabled and the other has only sslv3.
if i connect to first webservice and the protocol is tls, then the second webservice only has sslv3, will this cause the issue of the connection failure.

Comment: Depends on what you use but you should be able to turn on/off sslv3 support per connection you make. Client connections from an application are also unrelated to the ssl/tls protocols enabled on the server side of that application.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a web services then they obliged to have a http urls you can access to. You can just call them using https protocol through HttpsURLConnection (or any other library).